# How do you repeat linear regressions where only the IV changes without having to write code repeatedly?

Tags: r, variables, linear-regression, repeat, substitution

How do you repeat linear regressions where only the IV changes without having to write code repeatedly?

I have RStudio on MacOS 11.1. I want to get the `summary()` results of 8 linear regressions using the `mtcars` dataset, with the DV as `mpg`, and where the 1 IV in each regression model varies. The IVs of interest are `am`, `cyl`, `disp`, `hp`, `drat`, `wt`, `qsec`, and `vs`.

I could just rewrite the code each time for the different regressions, but this seems like the long way to complete this task.

For example, this would be code for the first regression:

```
lm__am_on_mpg__mtcars <- lm(mpg ~ am, data=mtcars)
summary(lm__am_on_mpg__mtcars)
```

And this would be the code for the second regression:

```
lm__cyl_on_mpg__mtcars <- lm(mpg ~ cyl, data=mtcars)
summary(lm__cyl_on_mpg__mtcars)
```

But I'd have to do this multiple times, and it seems like there could be a way to do this that is more concise.

Here are my questions: (1) Is this possible to do in R? (1a) If so, how would it be done?

====================

Here is my R code that I used to complete this task the long way:

```
# How do you repeat linear regressions where only the IV changes without having to write code repeatedly?

## dataset of interest
mtcars

### info about dataset
head(mtcars)
str(mtcars)
columns(mtcars)

## variables of interets
unique(mtcars$mpg)
# ---- NOTE: DV is mpg
unique(mtcars$am)
# ---- NOTE: IV is mpg
unique(mtcars$cyl)
unique(mtcars$disp)
unique(mtcars$hp)
unique(mtcars$drat)
unique(mtcars$wt)
unique(mtcars$qsec)
unique(mtcars$vs)
# ---- NOTE: other IVs of interest

## first linear regression
lm__am_on_mpg__mtcars <- lm(mpg ~ am, data=mtcars)
summary(lm__am_on_mpg__mtcars)

## linear regressions for the other IVs

### IV is cyl
lm__cyl_on_mpg__mtcars <- lm(mpg ~ cyl, data=mtcars)
summary(lm__cyl_on_mpg__mtcars)

### IV is disp
lm__disp_on_mpg__mtcars <- lm(mpg ~ disp, data=mtcars)
summary(lm__disp_on_mpg__mtcars)

### IV is hp
lm__hp_on_mpg__mtcars <- lm(mpg ~ hp, data=mtcars)
summary(lm__hp_on_mpg__mtcars)

### IV is drat
lm__drat_on_mpg__mtcars <- lm(mpg ~ drat, data=mtcars)
summary(lm__drat_on_mpg__mtcars)

### IV is wt
lm__wt_on_mpg__mtcars <- lm(mpg ~ wt, data=mtcars)
summary(lm__wt_on_mpg__mtcars)

### IV is qsec
lm__qsec_on_mpg__mtcars <- lm(mpg ~ qsec, data=mtcars)
summary(lm__qsec_on_mpg__mtcars)

### IV is vs
lm__vs_on_mpg__mtcars <- lm(mpg ~ vs, data=mtcars)
summary(lm__vs_on_mpg__mtcars)
```

====================

EDIT 1:

As per a suggestion from a commenter, I tried to install the ExhaustiveSearch package onto my RStudio console on MacOS, but it didn't work. Here is the console results below, just for reference.

```
> install.packages("ExhaustiveSearch")
Package which is only available in source form, and may need compilation of C/C++/Fortran:
  ‘ExhaustiveSearch’
Do you want to attempt to install these from sources? (Yes/no/cancel) yes
installing the source package ‘ExhaustiveSearch’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/ExhaustiveSearch_1.0.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 52611 bytes (51 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 51 KB

* installing *source* package ‘ExhaustiveSearch’ ...
** package ‘ExhaustiveSearch’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
clang++ -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -std=gnu++11 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/Rcpp/include' -I'/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/RcppArmadillo/include' -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c Combination.cpp -o Combination.o
clang++ -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -std=gnu++11 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/Rcpp/include' -I'/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/RcppArmadillo/include' -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c ExhaustiveSearchCpp.cpp -o ExhaustiveSearchCpp.o
clang++ -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -std=gnu++11 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/Rcpp/include' -I'/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/RcppArmadillo/include' -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c GLM.cpp -o GLM.o
clang++ -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -std=gnu++11 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/Rcpp/include' -I'/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/RcppArmadillo/include' -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
clang++ -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -std=gnu++11 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/Rcpp/include' -I'/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/RcppArmadillo/include' -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c SearchTask.cpp -o SearchTask.o
clang -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/Rcpp/include' -I'/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/RcppArmadillo/include' -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c lbfgs.c -o lbfgs.o
clang++ -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -std=gnu++11 -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined dynamic_lookup -single_module -multiply_defined suppress -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib -L/usr/local/lib -o ExhaustiveSearch.so Combination.o ExhaustiveSearchCpp.o GLM.o RcppExports.o SearchTask.o lbfgs.o -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib -lRlapack -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib -lRblas -L/usr/local/gfortran/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin18/8.2.0 -L/usr/local/gfortran/lib -lgfortran -lquadmath -lm -F/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/.. -framework R -Wl,-framework -Wl,CoreFoundation
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/gfortran/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin18/8.2.0'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/gfortran/lib'
ld: library not found for -lgfortran
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [ExhaustiveSearch.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘ExhaustiveSearch’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/ExhaustiveSearch’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘ExhaustiveSearch’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/w_/fc17blzn66v_j8xbm24vpmvm0000gn/T/RtmppjIa4V/downloaded_packages’
> 
> library(ExhaustiveSearch)
Error in library(ExhaustiveSearch) : 
  there is no package called ‘ExhaustiveSearch’
> install.packages("ExhaustiveSearch")
Package which is only available in source form, and may need compilation of C/C++/Fortran:
  ‘ExhaustiveSearch’
Do you want to attempt to install these from sources? (Yes/no/cancel) No
> library(ExhaustiveSearch)
Error in library(ExhaustiveSearch) : 
  there is no package called ‘ExhaustiveSearch’
> 
> install.packages("ExhaustiveSearch")
Package which is only available in source form, and may need compilation of C/C++/Fortran:
  ‘ExhaustiveSearch’
Do you want to attempt to install these from sources? (Yes/no/cancel) cancel
Error in install.packages : Cancelled by user
> library(ExhaustiveSearch)
Error in library(ExhaustiveSearch) : 
  there is no package called ‘ExhaustiveSearch’
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1)** Use `update` to modify the first fit:

```
fm.am <- lm(mpg ~ am, mtcars)
fm.cyl <- update(fm.am, ~ cyl)
```

**2)** If you want to iterate over all the columns use reformulate to construct the appropriate formula for each iteration.  Here L is set to a list of lm objects, one per run.  For example, L$cyl is the lm output for mpg ~ cyl.

In the code below we could have used the simpler commented out version of lmfun but the output won't look quite as nice if we do that.

```
# lmfun <- function(x) lm(reformulate(x, "mpg"), mtcars)
lmfun <- function(x) do.call("lm", list(reformulate(x, "mpg"), quote(mtcars)))
L <- Map(lmfun, names(mtcars)[-1])
```

**3)** If the idea is to determine which predictor variable is best try:

```
library(ExhaustiveSearch)
ExhaustiveSearch(mpg ~., mtcars, family = "gaussian", combsUpTo = 1)>
```

or if you want to find out which pair works best use comboUpTo=2, etc.  The output for the above code is as follows.  Note that smaller AICs are better.

```
Starting the exhaustive evaluation.

 Runtime          |  Completed      |  Status
--------------------------------------
--------------------------------------

Evaluation finished successfully.


+-------------------------------------------------+
|            Exhaustive Search Results            |
+-------------------------------------------------+
Model family:          gaussian 
Intercept:             TRUE 
Performance measure:   AIC 
Models fitted on:      training set (n = 32)
Models evaluated on:   training set (n = 32)
Models evaluated:      10  
Models saved:          10 
Total runtime:         00d 00h 00m 09s 
Number of threads:     4 

+-------------------------------------------------+
|                Top Feature Sets                 |
+-------------------------------------------------+
       AIC Combination
1 166.0294          wt
2 169.3064         cyl
3 170.2094        disp
4 181.2386          hp
5 190.7999        drat
```

Comment: Thanks. Options 1 and 2 seemed to work. Option 3 didn't work because my console couldn't install the package ExhaustiveSearch. I'll put the error as an edit in the text of the question.

Comment: Assuming you are on Windows if you are looking for a binary version you may need to wait for a few days until CRAN builds it as the package is new. If you want to use it sooner than that you will need to install Rtools40 from https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/ and then install ExhaustiveSearch and from source.

Comment: That's prob the issue. I am on MacOS, and I can't get access to windows.

Comment: It is not a windows only package.

Comment: Okay. Will try again on MacOS and let you know if I have better luck.

Comment: Either wait for the MacOS binary to be built -- should occur witihin a few days -- or build it from source yourself.\

Comment: Regarind the update at the end of your post see https://developer.r-project.org/Blog/public/2020/11/02/will-r-work-on-apple-silicon/index.html  I don't have a Mac myself but maybe someone else who does can provide some additional insight.

Answer (score 1):

Using lapply and as.formula to create a list with each lm object

```
library(tidyverse)

data_df <- mtcars %>% as_tibble()
##Target variables
target_vars <- c("cyl","disp","hp",
                 "drat","wt",
                 "qsec","vs")

##Write lapply and save summary objects

list_with_lm_objects <- lapply(target_vars, function(i){
      lm_object <- lm(as.formula(paste0("mpg ~",i)),data = data_df)
      summary_of_lm <- summary(lm_object)
      return(summary_of_lm)
})
    
z
```