# How do you do linear regressions on all possible combinations of variables?

Tags: r, for-loop, linear-regression

I am trying to do several scaled linear regressions in an automated way, not manually typing every possible combination of variables.

I have 20 variables. I want to run a regression on each pair and then each set of 3, 4, etc.

So, I'd want a regression comparing `Y ~ X1, X2`, `Y ~ X2, X3`.... `Y~ X1, X3`, `Y~X1,X2,X3`, `Y~X1,X2,X3,X4`, `Y~X1,X2,X3,X5,X7`, `Y~X1, X3, X7, X8` etc,etc. There would be a lot of models. Does anyone know how to do this?

I tried this ([How do you repeat linear regressions where only the IV changes without having to write code repeatedly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65744779/how-do-you-repeat-linear-regressions-where-only-the-iv-changes-without-having-to)):

```
lmfun <- function(x) do.call("lm", list(reformulate(x, "retention_rate"), quote(data)))
L <- Map(lmfun, names(data)[-1])
```

It works wonderfully except that I need the other combinations (3, 4, 5, 6 variables, etc, etc, not just iterating through a single X variable. Does anyone know how to change the above code to get the different combinations of different quantities? Also open to new suggestions.

Comment: There's packages for this, e.g. the `leaps` package, or the answer you link to uses `library(ExhaustiveSearch)`--- did you try that? You can search for "best subset regression" to find lots of resources. Also pay attention to the cautionary advice - this technique isn't always useful. You could also look at other variable selection techniques, the LASSO (in the `glmnet` package) is a very popular way to do variable selection, and arguably less problematic.

Comment: Also see `MuMIn::dredge()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `combn` in a `lapply` loop to create the formulas. Note that you'l have 1M+ regression formulas.

```r
xvars <- paste0("X", 1:20)

fmla_list <- lapply(2:20, \(k){
  combn(xvars, k, \(x) {
    regr <- paste(x, collapse = "+")
    fmla <- paste("Y ~", regr)
    as.formula(fmla)
  }, simplify = FALSE)
})
fmla_list <- unlist(fmla_list)

length(fmla_list)
#> [1] 1048555
sum(choose(20, 2:20))
#> [1] 1048555
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

You can also run the regressions in `combn`. In its last code line instead of returning `as.formula`, run `lm(as.formula(fmla), etc)`.

Answer (score 0):

The `stepwise` function from MASS package uses a method that could be useful for your porpouses: through comparing different kind of diagnostic indicators, sistematically eliminates or incorporates variables (backward/forward elimination). Here it's documentation link: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/Rcmdr/versions/2.0-4/topics/stepwise